# Retrofit POST method with url + json return Method Not allowed

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

My POST API is like this: `https://out-test.com/test/out/{ "key":"value" }`

When I copy paste URL in browser works without any problem it accepts it. 
But in Android, I get a response `Method Not Allowed`.

my API call:

```
@POST
Call<OUT> updateOUT( @Url String urlWithJson );
```

Retrofit declaration:

```
     //  Retrofit2 implementation
    String BASE_API_URL = "https://out-test.com/";
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl( BASE_API_URL )
            .addConverterFactory( GsonConverterFactory.create() )
            .build();

    final OutAPI api = retrofit.create( OutAPI.class );
```

Parsing object into String ( I got right JSON I validate it already ):

```
 Gson gson = new Gson();
            String jsonString = gson.toJson(out);
            String url = "test/out/" + jsonString;
```

And then I call POST :

```
 api.updateOut( url ).enqueue(new Callback<Out>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<Out> call, Response<Out> response) {
       Log.d(TAG, "onResponse:" + response );
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<Out> call, Throwable t) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: " + t);
    }
 });
```

Does anyone have an idea what I am doing wrong here to get back this response? Did I miss somewhere something? Searched on the internet, but didn't find any working solution.

@EDIT:
When I debug and look at response and URL if I copy the value of URL and paste into Browser, it works fine.

Greetings

Comment: can you post a more elaborated form of your url?

Comment: Either is in url error or server side error. Try to put in `@POST("test/out/")` and than just in `@Url` provide `JSON`. I recommend using `Postman` when working with API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Feel kinda stupid, but the problem was a guy who created API provided me the wrong documentation. A request is not POST but it's GET. However still had a problem with an error, but this time it was the wrong `Content-Type` which was `text/plain` instead of `application/json`. Thank you, everyone, for helping me out with this one. As @Yupi suggested Postman was a tool to debug this problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

```
@POST
Call<OUT> updateOUT( @Url String urlWithJson );
```

this with following.

```
@POST("test/out/{key_value}")
Call<OUT> updateOUT(@Path("key_value") String keyAndValue);
```

Then, update your rest of the code as below

```
//  Retrofit2 implementation

String BASE_API_URL = "https://out-test.com/";
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl( BASE_API_URL )
            .addConverterFactory( GsonConverterFactory.create() )
            .build();

final OutAPI api = retrofit.create( OutAPI.class );

Gson gson = new Gson();
String jsonString = gson.toJson(out);

api.updateOut(jsonString).enqueue(new Callback<Out>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<Out> call, Response<Out> response) {
       Log.d(TAG, "onResponse:" + response );
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<Out> call, Throwable t) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: " + t);
    }
 });
```

Comment: Did try this also. But same response

Comment: Did you try with this abstract method?

`@POST("test/out/{key_value}")
Call<OUT> updateOUT(@Path("key_value") String keyAndValue);`

Comment: Yeh, I did try this way. But got the same result. Actually, this first thought I did.

Comment: Acording to your question and your explanation you need to send a string as key value pairs. If you need to create a request like this `https://out-test.com/test/out/{ "key":"value" }` you need to send it as path parameter. Thats what my answer says. If your request is working in a browser please send more details about your end point. If the endpoint is POST and have some json body, how can you call that endpoint with a browser. Please re check your question and update your question with more details.

Comment: { "key": "value" } is just example for JSON Object. So https://out-test.com/test/out/JSON_OBJECT. Thank you for your answer. I will test few things ppl suggested. If nothing will work I will update my question with more details. Thank you again for now.

Answer (score 0):

Use Body provided by retrofit  and Do like this

```
@POST("test/out/")
    Call<OUT> updateOUT(@Body JsonObject urlWithJson );

    then follow
    Retrofit declaration:

         //  Retrofit2 implementation
        String BASE_API_URL = "https://out-test.com/";
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl( BASE_API_URL )
                .addConverterFactory( GsonConverterFactory.create() )
                .build();

    Then Pass your Json using GSON like:

    JsonObject jsonObj= new JsonObject
    jsonObj.addProperty("order",yourvalue) ;
    And then call POST :

     api.updateOut( jsonObj).enqueue(new Callback<Out>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Out> call, Response<Out> response) {
           Log.d(TAG, "onResponse:" + response );
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Out> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: " + t);
        }
     });
```

Comment: I know this one. But if I am not mistaken. This adds into your POST body and not in URL ( kinda newb at this in theory )? Sadly I am not able to change API.